# Is it possible to put Quotation marks („) into Char

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to `push_back()` a `„` symbol to a `std::vector<char>`.

I keep getting an error:

> character too large for enclosing character literal type

```
void CharVect (std::vector<char>&temp)
{
    temp.push_back('-');
    temp.push_back(',');
    temp.push_back('.');
    temp.push_back('?');
    temp.push_back('!');
    temp.push_back(':');
    temp.push_back(';');
    temp.push_back('(');
    temp.push_back(')');
    temp.push_back('„'); // error
    temp.push_back('”'); // error, but " works
    temp.push_back('{');
    temp.push_back('}');
    temp.push_back('*');
    temp.push_back('#');
}
```

Comment: That symbol is a multibyte character. It willl not fit in a `char`.

Comment: You're probably using a smart quote (unicode multi-byte character) rather than a "

Comment: @Oskaras Which compiler do you use?

Comment: thank you for your answers, @DmitryKuzminov I am using g++ compiler.

Comment: That could be a problem of the encoding of the source file. Two different (from binary perspective) source files could produce the same printout.

P.S. I tried that using online compiler - I see no errors.

Comment: @OskarasDiraitis, Could you please provide the HEX representation of the line of code with those quotes?

Comment: To be honest, it will depend on how you intend to use this vector, as to how best to organise it. If the rest of the code is byte char based, you will pay some to convert these wide chars into utf-8 strings when you want to write them, or the other way if you want to compare them.

Comment: What are you using this vector for? Do you actually *need* `'„'` and `'”'` in there? If you are using this vector as a list of ascii punctuation characters, then they don't belong there. (but `"` do.) If, on the other hand you want a list of unicode punctuation characters, then *a lot* of them are missing.

Comment: I am using this vector to erase chars from strings. I am trying to write a code that use map container and counts how many times each word appeared in the text, so I need to erase these punctuation marks from strings.

Comment: I assume this vector will contain the same values on every run on your program? Then a read-only array declared globaly or static would be a better choice than a vector.

Comment: You are right. Thank you.

Comment: If you are using a code page that supports `'„'` as a single byte encoding point, and your compiler supports that code page localization, and your editor is using that code page, and your file is saved in that code page encoding format, then your code will work.  Otherwise, you may be interested in investigating Unicode options in C++.

Answer (score 2):

Use `wchar_t`:

```
#include <vector>

void CharVect(std::vector<wchar_t> &temp)
{
    temp.push_back(L'-');
    temp.push_back(L',');
    temp.push_back(L'.');
    temp.push_back(L'?');
    temp.push_back(L'!');
    temp.push_back(L':');
    temp.push_back(L';');
    temp.push_back(L'(');
    temp.push_back(L')');
    temp.push_back(L'„'); // works
    temp.push_back(L'”'); // works
    temp.push_back(L'{');
    temp.push_back(L'}');
    temp.push_back(L'*');
    temp.push_back(L'#');
}
```

## [Live Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/38aTMV)

Or you may consider using `std::wstring` to store wide characters.

As [Gem Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8477999/gem-taylor) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56225788/is-it-possible-to-put-quotation-marks-into-char/56226107?noredirect=1#comment99073214_56226107), you might need to consider using `wchar32_t` if you ever need to handle extended Emoji.

Comment: This is a case where wide char does add value, and it is fairly painless to convert it to utf-8 if the rest of your string handling code is byte based. On the other hand, it will depend on how you are going to use this temp vector.

Comment: If you think you might need to handle extended Emoji, though you might want to concider using utf-32 wchar32_t! https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/test/Lexer/char-literal.cpp

Comment: `wchar32_t` won't be enough for handling every unicode case (i.e ""). Many unicode "characters" are a sequence of multiple code-points. Which means multiple `wchar32_t`. Unless you are doing font-rendering, stick with utf-8 everywhere.